Return AA Command L8 payshiled 10K
but my english is very bad.
I need help with an L8 command on payshiled 10k.
I made the settings according to the manual, but the command return is returning AA. I don't know if there is something with the private RSA header, which is with N in the export option. Has anyone ever seen something like this?
I'm trying to generate a key pair with the EI command and export option S, but without success either.

Hi Guilherme and welcome to Stack overflow! Help us help you by adding details to your question. What are those settings? Add your test private key to the question. Add a small, isolated but complete code snippet that reproduces the problem. What is the complete error message you get (in text, not a screenshot).
